# Search Contact name from ABAddressBook using NSPredicate for iOS

Tags: ios, nspredicate, abaddressbook

I am creating Custom phone book.
In search bar functionality i need to search specific contact using text entered.
so what predicate should i write which will filter Array from Addressbook Array of type ABrecord?
it should be something like name begins with "text"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
NSArray *allPeople = CFBridgingRelease(ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook));
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id person, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    NSString *firstName = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));
    if (firstName && [firstName rangeOfString:searchTerm options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location == 0)
        return TRUE;

    NSString *lastName = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)person, kABPersonLastNameProperty));
    if (lastName && [lastName rangeOfString:searchTerm options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location == 0)
        return TRUE;

    // repeat for all of the properties you want to search

    return FALSE;
}];
NSArray *searchResults = [allPeople filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

---

Note, if doing lots of these searches, and you want to void doing this `ABRecordCopyValue` inside the block, you can create your own array of custom objects (or dictionaries) with whatever keys you want, thereby doing this `ABRecordCopyValue` once for all of your fields for all of your records, and then you can use `predicateWithFormat` on your array of custom objects repeatedly without incurring the overhead of doing `ABRecordCopyValue` repeatedly. But I don't believe that Apple has ever published keys that one could use with array of `ABRecordRef` that you can use in conjunction with `predicateWithFormat` yourself.

---

If you just wanted to search for the name, you could also use `ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName`, which eliminates the need for the predicate altogether:

```
NSArray *searchResults = CFBridgingRelease(ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(addressBook, (__bridge CFStringRef)searchTerm));
```

Answer (score 0):

why you wana use NSPredicate ? ... look at this link if it is  [helpful](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AddressBook/Tasks/Tasks/Tasks/Tasks/Searching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001024-BABHHIHC")!

Comment: This link is not opening .. want to use nspredicate for faster search. i have 5000+ contacts

Comment: Judging by the URL, I think this was [the intended link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AddressBook/Tasks/Searching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001024-BABHHIHC). Unfortunately, that's for the Mac OS Address Book framework, not the iOS framework (which is different).